# Platform Exception in Flutter - How to handle

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am new to `Flutter` and I'm trying to implement email authentication using `Firebase` This is local authentication. I am getting platform exception as follows:
[platform exception flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fNjp.png)

What I have implemented is :

```
void signInWithEmailPassword()
async {
  UserCredential user;
  try {
  user = await mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text);
  Navigator.pushNamed(context,'/page1_menu');
  }on PlatformException catch(e){
    print('e.message');
  }
  finally
  {
    if(user != null){
      print('User signed in'); 
    } 
  }

}
```

Please feel free to access the above link for exception. The `signInWithEmailPassword()` is called inside a `RaisedButton` labelled as `Login`

I tried finding the solution on internet, but no where I found helpful content or maybe I was not able to understand. Could you please help?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, don't show pictures of code and text.  Copy all relevant information into the question and format it so it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: Thank you for correcting :]